# A line through $P=(\sqrt3,0)$ and at an angle of $\pi/3$ with the positive direction of x axis cuts the parabola $y^2=x+2$ at A and B

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

> A line passing through $P=(\sqrt3,0)$ and making an angle of $\pi/3$ with the positive direction of x axis cuts the parabola $y^2=x+2$ at A and B, then:
>   (a)$PA+PB=2/3$
>   (b)$|PA-PB|=2/3$
>   (c)$(PA)(PB)=\frac{4(2+\sqrt3)}{3}$
>   (d)$\frac{1}{PA}+\frac{1}{PB}=\frac{2-\sqrt3}{2}$

Equation of line:
$y=\sqrt3(x-\sqrt3)$
$y=\sqrt3x-3$

substituting $y=\sqrt3x-3$ in $y^2=x+2$

$(\sqrt3x-3)^2=x+2$
$3x^2-6\sqrt3x+9=x+2$
$3x^2-(6\sqrt3+1)x+7=0$

$x_A=\frac{(6\sqrt3+1)+\sqrt{(6\sqrt3+1)^2-84}}{6}$
$x_B=\frac{(6\sqrt3+1)-\sqrt{(6\sqrt3+1)^2-84}}{6}$

But this gives a very complicated value of $x$ and that makes me feel that there ought to be a shorter way to solve this question, just can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C,D$ be the point on $x$-axis such that $AC\perp CP,BD\perp PD$ respectively.

Then, $\triangle{PAC},\triangle{PBD}$ are triangles with $30^\circ,60^\circ,90^\circ$ from which we have
$$PA=\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}AC=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}|A_y|,\qquad PB=\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}|B_y|$$

Eliminating $x$ from the system gives
$$y^2=\frac{y+3}{\sqrt 3}+2\implies \sqrt 3\ y^2-y-3-2\sqrt 3=0$$
from which we have
$$A_y+B_y=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3},\qquad A_yB_y=\frac{-3-2\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 3}$$

(a) is not correct since
$$PA+PB\gt \frac{2(A_y+B_y)}{\sqrt 3}=\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}=\frac 23$$

(b) is correct since
$$|PA-PB|=\left|\frac{2(A_y+B_y)}{\sqrt 3}\right|=\frac 23$$

(c) is correct since
$$PA\times PB=\frac 43\left|\frac{-3-2\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 3}\right|=\frac{4(2+\sqrt 3)}{3}$$

(d) is not correct since
$$\frac{1}{PA}+\frac{1}{PB}=\frac{PA+PB}{PA\cdot PB}\gt \frac{2(A_y+B_y)}{\sqrt 3}\div \frac{4(2+\sqrt 3)}{3}=\frac{2-\sqrt 3}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let the feet of A and B on the x-axis be A’ and B’ respectively.

[image]

Compute $A’P$. It is … $\dfrac {1}{6} + \dfrac {\sqrt(\delta)}{6}$.

Similarly, $PB’ = -\dfrac {1}{6} + \dfrac {\sqrt(\delta)}{6}$.

Then, $|PA – PB| = 2 \times |A’P – PB’| = \dfrac {2}{3}$.